# List of all Ruby "special quotes"

Tags: ruby

E.g.:

```
> %w{Maine Michigan California}
=> ["Maine", "Michigan", "California"]

> %{a b}
=> "a b"
```

Where can I find a list of all of these? (And what are they called?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have heard them called percent methods before. They are mostly carry-overs from Perl. [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation) is a good list summarizing them

Answer (score 3):

They're called literals! Check this table:

http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.1

EDIT:

As Karl points out in the comments, the whole chunk isn't actually a literal; the percent sign signals that a literal will follow, while the letter specifies the type of the literal. The opening brace (though one could also use, for example, “(”, “[”, “{”, or “<”) is a delimiter marking the beginning of a literal. From the link above:

> the literal consists of the characters
>   up to the matching closing delimiter,
>   taking account of nested delimiter
>   pairs. For all other delimiters, the
>   literal comprises the characters up to
>   the next occurrence of the delimiter
>   character.

Hope that helps! Apologies for the first, sloppier answer.

Comment: I must quibble with this: the entire expression is a "literal" (which is a pretty language-agnostic concept FWIW), but there appears to be no particular term for the part of the literal expression before the open brace.

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry about that. Just updated my answer to explain that a bit better.

Comment: The linked table is incomplete (it doesn't distinguish between `%w` and `%W`, and it doesn't include `%s` at all)

Comment: @HoraceLoeb Thanks for pointing that out. The book was written for Ruby 1.6; it appears that `%W` was introduced in 1.8.2; I haven't been able to find out when `%s` was introduced, but it's available in 1.8.6 at least.